# list of elements from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript array of unknown length and I'd love to make some of its fields show up in my html page.
I've tried to make a function in my js library to print them calling it directly through my html code

```
<body onload="parser()">
   <div id="list">
       <script> load_list() </script>
   </div>
</body>
```

the function parser() extract the infos from an xml file and put them in the array. The function load_list is the following

```
function load_list () {
     document.write ("<ul>");
     for (i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
         document.write ("<li><a href='javascript:change("+array[i].x+")'>");
         document.write (array[i].name);
         document.write ("</a></li>");
     }
}
```

Comment: do you have an element in which the new elements has to be added

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: make the function load_list work. At the moment this doesn't show anything. I don't know if the problem is in the html code or in the javascript!

Comment: you are looping through subjects object (whatever that is) and then you print array[] element?

Comment: I'd say, try not to depend on document.write, the problem is so much easier if you think of a container that needs to be filled with some elements.

Comment: bunch of question to ask here. 1. what is subjects and where is it defined? 2. where is array defined? ...

Comment: @BojanKovacevic just a mistake on copyin that. this is not the problem. array is defined as global in the js library

Comment: @Frederik I think that what you've just said it's possible knowing the number of elements, but I can't

Comment: well how do you expect us to help you and you did not put all relevant code? we can only say what is the problem with code we see here.

Comment: there is no other relevant code. is it so relevant to know where an array filled in a function and used in another one is declared? I guess there's only one place where this could be declared...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="list">
</div>

<script>
    var subjects = [{
        x: '1',
        name: 'One'
    }]

    function load_list(){
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(ul);
        for (i=0; i< subjects.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.innerHTML = subjects[i].name;
            a.setAttribute('href', "javascript:change("+subjects[i].x+")")
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }


    function parser(){

        //do parsing logic


        load_list()
    }

</script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bkxxV/5/)

Comment: there is a typo in the anchor element definition, here and in the Fiddle :)

Comment: @Arun P Johny createElement('li') should be createElement('a');

Comment: do i call the function inside the div?

Comment: var a = document.createElement('li'); <---- can't edit myself, too short

Comment: @Janinho67 No, you'd call this from the head, or in the body below the DIV, as it gets the element by ID, all it needs is for the DIV to have loaded. In the fiddle, it is being called in the head onload.

Comment: @Janinho67 no need, you can call the `load_list()` on `window.onload`

Comment: @Janinho67 call the `load_list()` at the end of the `parser` method

Answer (score 2):

document.write is essentially deprecated (not officially).

Further reading:
[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Also, the creating of elements through straight text is again unwise, as it doesn't properly add them to the DOM.

Try this:

```
subjects = ["test","test2"];
array = [{x:"test",name:"name"},{x:"test2",name:"name2"}];

for (i=0; i< subjects.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href","javascript:change("+array[i].x+")");
    a.innerHTML = array[i].name;
    li.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('listUL').appendChild(li);
}

<div id="list">
    <ul id="listUL">

    </ul>
</div>
```

See it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdkmz/

Comment: it was useful SpAm thank you. I've already marked the other answer as "correct" but i give you a thumb up as well!

Comment: Thankyou, much appreciated. The two answers are essentially the same anyway :)